# How to delete a provisioning file for xcode

Tags: xcode

I ever tried to create a provisioning file and certificate in the apple's developer manager web page.And latter on,I want to delete them all.I did delete the certificate,while I just failed to do so with the provisioning file.Here is the issue:

1. I logged in the Apple's Developer Manage Web page and delete the provisioning file.then I refresh the web page.It seemed to be
   successful.
2. I open my Xcode and click the preference menu the view all the
   provisioning files.And I did open the directory and deleted all the
       provisioning files I had downloaded already.and then I refresh the
       panel.It seemed to be the same as the web page.I clicked "download
       all".
3. I closed the Xcode window and exit.

   4.I refreshed the web page.The provisioning file that I want to delete appeared again with a suffix “managed by Xcode”.

So could any kind guy tell me what this shit really is and how to delete this shit?Please,give me some help.

Comment: If the provisioning profiles are going into *Managed by Xcode* state, then I would assume that Xcode projects still exist that use/need provisioning profiles, so Xcode is auto-generating and managing them.  They will never go away all the time this is the case.  Also you don't need to use profanity, although I understand that profiles, certificates, etc are very frustrating.

Comment: I did searched all my mac's directory and the provisioning file did not exist on my mac.But it's very strange how the Xcode could contain a file that was created by my certificate which also had been deleted.I guess it's all because the provisioning file just still exists in the apple's server,and when I tried to delete it and the apple would try to delete the file tag as a response to my deleting action,but this time it failed.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to

```
~/Library/MobileDevice/
```

and delete all the profiles from there

Comment: Bit of a hammer to crack a nut?

Comment: I did do this at my second step as I explained.It's nonsense ,either.

Comment: What makes me confused is that I could deleted some other provisioning files successfully by those steps I explained as above.But only this one failed.

Answer (score 0):

Goto https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/

Choose the provisioning profile you want to delete. You will see the image below. Use the Delete button.

[image]

Comment: I did do this at my first step as I explained.But it made no sense as I explained by the flower steps.